# Python requires mysqlclient v 21, but updated brew package is v 22

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, libmysql, libmysqlclient

I made a big mistake, updated brew packages (my python packages are also up to date)

And now in brew there is only version 22 of mysqlclient in default mysql v 8.1.0

But python still requires v21 of mysqlclient.

So it looks for `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.1.0/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib`

But there is only `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.1.0/lib/libmysqlclient.22.dylib`

So how should i manga this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where my app was trying to find v21 but my system has v22 after Sonoma update. I guess this was because I installed mysql using brew install mysql which installed a non-compatible version. For me this worked in letting my app run :

```
brew install mysql@8.0
brew link mysql@8.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it would deffinetly work, but i don't want old version of mysql on my system, so i ended up with just creating copy of libmysqlclient.22.dylib renamed to libmysqlclient.21.dylib

Comment: Same. I was updating my opensearch and it updated a bunch of other stuff and I got the said error. Somehow I have mysql@8.0 AND mysql@8.1, but both don't have v21. I ended up copying a v22 and renaming it to v21